# List files for loop "i" iteractions

Tags: r, regex, loops, csv, export-to-csv

I have a directory with with files named something like `name_1_class.csv`, `name_1_school.csv`, ... `name_10_class.csv`, `name_10_school.csv`

I am reading these files from the directory, and after subsetting the csvs, I combine them into a single file and write it out to a new directory that has an iteration name. Although I managed to run this code with indexes specified directly, I would like to create a function that would read the pattern of the csv files based on the i as the number of iteration.

The code I have below obviously does not work, i.e.

```
school <- list.files(pattern="1-school.csv" )
```

when `1` is specified works OK, but I have not figured out how to abstract the indexing to `i` in regex.

How do I specify the pattern based on a sequence of iterations? All suggestions are appreciated (obviously I am new to this).

```
d <- 1:10

for (i in 1:length(d)) {

    school <- list.files(pattern=i"-school.csv" )
    class <- list.files(pattern=i"_class.csv" )

    school <- data.frame(lapply(school, read.csv))
    class <- data.frame(lapply(class, read.csv))

    school <- data.frame(school[, c(2,4,5)])
    school$school <- rep("school")

    class <- data.frame(class[, c(2:4)])
    class$class <- rep("class")


    df <- rbind(school,class)
    dir.create(paste0("iteration",i), showWarnings = FALSE)

    write.csv(df, file.path(paste0("iteration",i), "output_file.csv"), row.names=FALSE)

}
```

Comment: What is the actual range of files you want to read?

Comment: the total number of files in the directory is twenty. two files for each iteration.i.e. ten is the range, if I understand the question correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste the number `i` to your string, and search for that. Like this:

```
school <- list.files(pattern=paste0(i,"_school.csv" ))
class <- list.files(pattern=paste0(i,"_class.csv" ))
```

Example:

```
i=1

list.files(pattern=".csv")
  "csv1.csv"                "csv2.csv"

list.files(pattern=paste0(i,".csv"))
  "csv1.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use paste to create strings from variables.

ie

```
for (i in 1:n){(paste("df",i,sep="") <-read.csv(paste(i,"-school.csv",sep="") }
```

And similar for the class

Comment: This method also needs to use "assign" as the first part only creates a string.